# Getting the UUID of eddystone beacon using android beacon library

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon, beacon, eddystone

i'm using **eddystone beacon** and **android beacon library(AltLib)**, I'm a beginner user with these beacons; and for my project.
i want to get the UUID of the beacon and to display it on a EditView or TextView.
So i tried some code but no way!I obtained an endless execution... AS :

```
public class BeaconActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements BeaconConsumer {

    public static final String TAG = "BeaconsEverywhere";
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_beacon);

        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
            .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

        beaconManager.bind(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        final Region region = new Region("myBeaons", Identifier.parse("<replaceBySomeUIID>"), null, null);

        beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "didEnterRegion");
                    beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "didExitRegion");
                    beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {

            }
        });

        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                for(Beacon oneBeacon : beacons) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "distance: " + oneBeacon.getDistance() + " id:" + oneBeacon.getId1() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId2() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId3());
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_beacon, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Suddenly I do not understand...! Can someone help me on this part?

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

- Eddystone-UID beacons don't have UUIDs (16 byte universally unique identifiers) as identifiers.  Instead, they have a 10 byte Namespace Id and a 6 byte Instance Id.  With the Android Beacon Library, `beacon.getId1()` returns the 10 byte Namespace Id and `beacon.getId2()` returns the 6 byte instance Id.
- To match Eddystone-UID beacons, you need to set up a beacon parser for that beacon type.  Like this:

  ```
  beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
      .setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
  ```
- If you want to match *all* Eddystone beacons regardless of identifiers, so you can read the identifiers of any beacon nearby, set up your region with all identifiers set to null like this:

  ```
  final Region region = new Region("myBeacons", null, null, null);
  ```
- Then when any Eddystone-UID beacon is detected by ranging, you can print out its identifier to the log with the code you have already:

  ```
  public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
          for(Beacon oneBeacon : beacons) {
              Log.d(TAG, "distance: " + oneBeacon.getDistance() + " id:" + oneBeacon.getId1() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId2() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId3());
          }
    }
  ```
- If you want to add the detected identifiers to an `EditView` named `myEditText`, you need to make sure it is already part of your Activity's layout.  If it is, you could do so like this:

  ```
  final String line = "Namespace id: " + oneBeacon.getId1() + ", Instance Id:" + oneBeacon.getId2());

  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          EditText editText = (EditText)BeaconActivity.this
                  .findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
          editText.append(line+"\n");                                 
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: is that a problem when i change the UUID's beacons to 00000000000000000000000000000001 ??

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "change the UUID's beacons"  Perhaps you can describe the steps you are taking to do this.

Comment: To be more precise, i'm using an ibks 105A beacon, and I have manually changed his UUID to "000....001" using the ibks config tool application. My question is : Does it impact his detection ? also, which beacon parser do I have to use ?
Also i'm not able to get the UUID yet

Comment: I suspect the beacon may not be configured for Eddystone.  I suggest you use an off-the-shelf detection app like [Locate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en) to confirm the frame type the beacon is advertising. I am not an expert on configuring the ibks 105A, so you really need to consult the manufacturer for instructions configuring it to transmit an Eddystone-UID beacon frame.  If you can put it in Eddystone UID mode, the BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT will pick it up.

Comment: Thank you very much David, but it's ok, i've found where was the problem : it was the beacon parser. Now it detects the beacons :)